# Firebase - how to change site for project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a project called 'myapp-12345' hosted on Firebase and the project has two sites:

- myapp.web.app
- myapp-12345.web.app -> this is the site used for project

What can I do to use 'myapp.web.app' instead of 'myapp-12345' ? When using Firebase CLI, I can't change the site where I want to host the project.

Comment: Which Firebase CLI commands did you use?

Comment: @Buczkowski I'm still pretty new with hosting on Firebase so the only things I did use are 'firebase init' and then 'firebase deploy'

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets - this should help you